# DayDream Permission Request

Tags: android, permissions, daydream

All I need to do is get permission in my daydream application, but I don't know how to write code.Please help me to solve this problem.

## below refer site and picture

> https://developers.google.com/vr/distribute/daydream/design-requirements

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If your application only supports Daydream then add this to your manifest file under `Application` tag:

```
<uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="true" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.sensor.accelerometer" android:required="true" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.sensor.gyroscope" android:required="true" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.vr.high_performance" android:required="true" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.software.vr.mode" android:required="true" />
```

Reference: [Daydream App Quality Requirements](https://developers.google.com/vr/distribute/daydream/functionality-requirements)